# Where can I find a clear derivation of backpropagation through a Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: neural-networks, references, proof, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Any links to books, articles or papers would be appreciated, or even a written explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to just leave a comment, but here is a link I have found generally useful:

http://deeplearning.net/reading-list/

In particular the first link at the top is to a book you might find useful, as well as some of the links in the CNN section.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to publicly up-vote this answer, but thank you very much! The chapter on Convolutional neural networks in the first link looks promising